# curl namelookup_time of 10 seconds

Tags: php, curl

When executing a basic curl request in PHP to a plain text web page (http://whatismyip.org/) it takes more than 10 seconds to respond.

After looking at the info from curl is tells me that the namelookup_time is 10 seconds. I can see the exact same result when executing curl from the command line (Terminal).

**Why does it take so long for the name lookup**, from what I've read it's more than likely something relating to the server/my computer from which the PHP file is hosted.

---

Here's my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "whatismyip.org");
curl_exec( $ch );

$ci = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($ci);
```

Here's the info:

```
[url] => HTTP://whatismyip.org 
[content_type] => text/plain 
[http_code] => 200 
[header_size] => 45 
[request_size] => 53 
[filetime] => -1 
[ssl_verify_result] => 0 
[redirect_count] => 0 
[total_time] => 10.549943 
[namelookup_time] => 10.100938 
[connect_time] => 10.300077 
[pretransfer_time] => 10.300079 
[size_upload] => 0 
[size_download] => 14 
[speed_download] => 1 
[speed_upload] => 0 
[download_content_length] => -1 
[upload_content_length] => 0 
[starttransfer_time] => 10.549919 
[redirect_time] => 0 
[certinfo] => Array ( )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't repeat this using exactly the code above - `namelookup_time` on my (Windows) machine comes back as `0`, with `total_time` being ~`0.5`. `namelookup_time` is the time the OS has taken to resolve the DNS name for `whatismyip.org`, so you need to examine your server's DNS configuration.

At a guess, your configured primary DNS server doesn't exist/doesn't work, and the timeout is 10 seconds. This means that the OS will wait 10 seconds trying to contact the primary DNS, and when this times out falls through to the secondary, which works.

What are your configured DNS server(s)? Try using `8.8.8.8` (Google) as your primary DNS, if needed.

As a side note, it is best to supply a **full** URL to cURL, so use `http://whatismyip.org/` instead of just `whatismyip.org` - although this does not seem to be the cause of this specific problem.

Comment: At the moment my DNS server when looking in `System Preferences>Network>Advanced>DNS` is `192.168.1.1`.

Comment: Just changed it to Googles `8.8.8.8` and it's working like a charm now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```

Solved the problem for me. IPV6 got an obscure bug.

Comment: That worked for me on a local Ubuntu vagrant box on OSX. I'm not sure why.  How did you determine it was a IPV6 issue?

Comment: I received a DNS error, then i i've tried to change some parameters.

Comment: Worked for me as well on a shared PHP hosting service. It was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 3):

Probably one of your DNS servers aren't replying in a timely fashion. Try this command for all IP's listed in /etc/resolv.conf:

```
dig @IP.TO.DNS.SERVER google.com
```

If I am correct, one of your DNS servers are not responding.

Comment: I now see you are using OSX, and you specified your own DNS settings. Probably your upstream router - which does the DNS lookups for you - has a faulty DNS config.

Comment: Actually `192.168.1.1` was the default but like you said it wasn't responding quick enough. Changing it to `8.8.8.8` as DaveRandom said seems to have fixed the problem. +1

Comment: Great. And if your default DNS server (192.168.1.1) takes more than 10 seconds to reply, there is something wrong there, or further "upstream" :-).