# PHP CURL: randomly very slow

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, php-curl

I have a frontend server which fetches data from a back-end server via CURL.

The problem is that CURL access is very slow every now and then. The standard time is about 0.3 seconds, about every 5th time but more than 2 seconds, sometimes even more than 10 seconds.
It's not the backend server, even if I curl to other websites the problem occurs.

curl_getinfo when it is slow:

```
    [url] => xxx
    [content_type] => application/json
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 325
    [request_size] => 189
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 8.588315
    [namelookup_time] => 2.8E-5
    [connect_time] => 1.543114
    [pretransfer_time] => 6.815358
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 5620
    [speed_download] => 654
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 8.588278
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 83.XXX.X.XXX
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )
```

curl_getinfo when it is fast:

```
    [url] => xxx
    [content_type] => application/json
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 325
    [request_size] => 189
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.333137
    [namelookup_time] => 0.004209
    [connect_time] => 0.004536
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.012719
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 5620
    [speed_download] => 16869
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.333101
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 83.XXX.X.XXX
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )
```

My CURL-Options:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

**EDIT**
It's not only PHP-CURL. When I try it via Command Line, it is sometimes very slow, sometimes very fast.

```
curl --get "https://my-test-website.com"
```

Same procedure as PHP-CURL.

Comment: Maybe this can help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712167/curl-namelookup-time-of-10-seconds

Comment: Try wget as well, it seems to be a namelookup_time issue.

Comment: It's always DNS

Comment: You get the effective donwload speed iwhen you substract starttransfer_time from total_time. As @JoséCarlosPHP has already commented, a slow DNS could trigger that. Consider using a local DNS cache/proxy, if that is all gibberish, contact your network admin. If you don't know who your network admin is for this case, get into the know first, you're depending on it.